# Successful Implementations of NAnt bcp (SQL Server) Task?

Tags: sql-server, nant, bcp, nantcontrib

I am looking for either a NAnt Task for SQL Server bcp, or the file format for bcp native output.

I supposed I could build a NAntContrib Task for bcp but I don't have time at the moment (Do we ever?).

Has anybody strolled this path before?  Advice?

Thanks - Jon

Comment: What are you using bcp for in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bcp doesn't have a native file output format as such, but can produce a binary file where the fields are prefixed by a 1-4 byte header that contains the length of the field.  The length of the header or the row/column delimiter formats are specified in the control file (format described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx)),

If using prefixed files, SQL Server bcp uses a -1 length in the header to denote nulls.

'Native' in bcp-speak refers to binary representations of the column data.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099919/what-are-the-binary-storage-formats-for-sqflt8-sqlmoney-and-other-native-sql-dat) has some discussion of these formats.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use NAnt's [`<exec>` task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) to drive bcp...